# System.Text.Json Serialization formatting issues

Tags: c#, system.text.json

In my ASP.NET Core application I am using the built-in System.Text.Json serializer to convert EF models to DTOs. On one of my models, I have a property that represents a percentage and I map that to a DTO property. Before returning the value to the client, I convert the value to a percentage. However, I am finding out that if my DTO property is a double and I serialize it I get odd results when doing the percentage conversion. It seems to work as expected when using a decimal property in my DTO. Anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Here is an illustration of the problem....

```
    var test = .14M;
    var formatted = test * 100;
    var bytes = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(formatted);
```

Serialized Result = 14.00

```
    var test = .14d;
    var formatted = test * 100;
    var bytes = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(formatted);
```

Serialized Result = 14.000000000000002

Comment: Binary floating-point is not exact with regards to decimal digits. The serializer does try to serialize the exact value, just in case you need to round-trip. Check `formatted.ToString("G17")` to see what I mean. The same does not apply to `decimal`, which (as the name implies) is a decimal floating-point type that can store your value exactly.

Comment: I changed the code that does the conversion to force the math to use decimals and then convert it back to a double. 

var formatted = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDecimal(value) * 100M)

seems to be an okay workaround for now.